# Extending dtypes? Best data structure for lists and relations?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, user-defined-types

I'm trying to fit an unstructured mesh consisting of (tetrahedral) cells, their (triangular) faces, edges, and nodes into a Python data structure that is both intuitive and efficient.
The questions that the data structure needs to be able to answer are "What are the coordinates of node k?", "Which edges are in cell j?", "Which cells are adjacent to face i?" and so forth.

My first guess was to go like

```
nodes_coords = np.array(num_nodes, dtype=np.dtype((float,3)))
cells_dtype = np.dtype([('nodes', (int,4))])
cells = np.array(num_cells, dtype=cells_dtype)
```

and so forth.
The advantage of this would be that there is a very intuitive way of getting the cell-node relations, namely

```
cells[4]['nodes']
```

would give you the nodes in cell #4.

There is one downside of this that I can see at the moment:
The arrays are not extendable. Suppose I decide later at run time that I would like to add information about faces and edges; how can I add fields to the cells array without moving around the data, i.e., how to dynamically extend dtypes of arrays?

A work-around would be to create separate arrays such as

```
cells_nodes = ...
cells_faces = ...
cells_edges = ...
```

and fill them whenever necessary. This doesn't seem very idiomatic though. For example, looping over cells where nodes, faces, and edges are required, would each time require zipping up the three arrays.

Helpful suggestions, anyone?

Comment: When you say "suppose I decide later that I would like to add [fields]", what exactly is it that you're worried about? Difficulty of modifying existing code to match when you add fields to cells_dtype? Difficulty of converting data previously serialized in the old format? Difficulty of using two different dtypes for cell data in the same program?

Comment: Oh I mean that I don't now how I efficiently add fields. I could of course go ahead and create a whole new array with an extended dtype, and fill the old entries back in bit by bit, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you mean by "efficiency". Are you talking about doing this at run-time and you're worried about the CPU and memory cost of copying arrays, or are you talking about editing source files full of numbers and you're worried about the time it will take you to edit them every time you change your storage structure? Or are you mostly interested in how to write the rest of your code so that you can minimize the amount of it that needs to change if you later add or remove fields?

Comment: Now I understand the misconception: By later I don't mean "later in life" but "later at runtime". The structure is usually created with nodes and cells only, and edges/faces can be added as needed. I'm worried about memory and CPU costs of adding edge/face information to an existing cells array, for example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'll say that I'm not really a numpy expert. I think that while there's probably no way to do what you describe, it's probably not as big a problem as you think.

As you describe it, you want to add fields but you want to avoid moving the data around. I think that's just not possible. Your options are:

1. Perhaps you know in advance which meshes will need extra fields? If so, you could allocate them up-front and carefully write your algorithms to ignore the fields they don't need to manipulate so that they can be used regardless of which extra fields exist in an array.
2. Just use the same dtype for all cells and ignore the fields when they're not used. Wastes some memory, but pretty easy. If possible,
3. Reallocate with a different dtype when you need to add a field. While this involves copying, do you do this often enough for the cost of the copy to be a problem? Copying numpy arrays is pretty quick, certainly compared to Python 'for' loops over that same data.
4. As you suggest, keep separate simple arrays for each field. While this might involve zipping for Python-based loops, presumably that's not the main sort of processing you're performing on them, is it? If mostly looping over numpy arrays in Python `for` loops you're probably not getting a lot of benefit out numpy.